# Can javax.net.ssl.SSLContext / SSLSocketFactory be stored in a static field?

Tags: ssl, static, websphere-liberty, sslcontext

Are javax.net.ssl.SSLContext and javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory safe to store in a static field of the class that uses it? Can I use the one object for everything? I'm using it in a TAI in WebSphere Liberty Profile.

Comment: what purpose do you have for storing it in a static field?  If it's the default context, could you just use `SSLContext.getDefault()` instead?

Comment: It isn't the default context, I've had to add a TrustManager and TrustStore.

Comment: Why not? If your entire application need to use the same `SSLContext` and want to use the same `SSLSocketFactory`, I see no harm there. But you have to be careful how you implement it